# TQueue gets never emptied if Dequeue used as a procedure parameter

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-synchronization

```
interface

type

TMulticastListenerThread = class(TThread)
strict private
  .....
  _queue: TQueue<string>;
  FOnReceive: TGetStrProc;
  procedure DoReceive();
  .....
public
  .....
  procedure Execute(); override;
  property OnReceive:TGetStrProc read FOnReceive write FOnReceive;
  .....
end;

implementation

procedure TMulticastListenerThread.Execute();
var addrlen: Integer;
    nbytes: Integer;
    msgbuf: array[1..MSGBUFSIZE] of AnsiChar;
    msgstr: AnsiString;
begin
  inherited;
  // now just enter a read-print loop
  while not Terminated do begin
    try
      if not _connected then begin
        Sleep(100);
        continue;
      end;
      addrlen := sizeof(addr);
      nbytes := recvfrom(fd, msgbuf, MSGBUFSIZE, 0, addr, addrlen);
      if (nbytes < 0) then begin
        perror('recvfrom');
      end
      else begin
        SetLength(msgstr, nbytes);
        Move(msgbuf, PAnsiChar(msgstr)^, nbytes);
        _queue.Enqueue(msgstr);
        Synchronize(DoReceive);
      end;
    except
      on ex: Exception do perror(ex.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Now all is about the synchronized `DoReceive` method.

If it contains such a code:

```
procedure TMulticastListenerThread.DoReceive();
begin
  while _queue.Count > 0 do
    if Assigned(FOnReceive) then FOnReceive(_queue.Dequeue());
end;
```

after I terminate my application it goes through the `while` loop again and again, `_queue.Count` is always `1`, although **no new strings are enqueued**, and `TMulticastListenerThread`'s destructor is never called.

When I dequeue through an intermediate **local string variable**:

```
procedure TMulticastListenerThread.DoReceive();
var s: string;
begin
  while _queue.Count > 0 do begin
    s := _queue.Dequeue();
    if Assigned(FOnReceive) then FOnReceive(s);
  end;
end;
```

application terminates normally and destructor is being called.

Could you explain this?

Comment: Your first approach will only clear the queue if Assigned(FOnReceive) returns true, while the second will do so in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In following code `_queue.Dequeue()` will execute only if you have assigned `FOnReceive` event handler.

```
procedure TMulticastListenerThread.DoReceive();
begin
  while _queue.Count > 0 do
    if Assigned(FOnReceive) then FOnReceive(_queue.Dequeue());
end;
```

However this code will call `_queue.Dequeue()` every time, before your assignment check.

```
procedure TMulticastListenerThread.DoReceive();
var s: string;
begin
  while _queue.Count > 0 do begin
    s := _queue.Dequeue();
    if Assigned(FOnReceive) then FOnReceive(s);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You are right. Now I understand what is happening. When destroying, FOnReceive gets un-assigned and the queue will never be emptied. I should sleep more.

Comment: We all need to sleep more :)